# Splash Screen drawable not found but Drawable clearly in project structure

Tags: android

I am trying to create a splash screen following this guide.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

I followed the steps line by line, however, I get an error saying the splash_background.xml isn't found.

Can anyone solve the problem? I really don't know what is wrong.

Project Structure:
[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dhew6.shopifyinternquestion">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</application>
```

SplashActivity:
    package com.example.dhew6.shopifyinternquestion;

```
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}}
```

background_splash.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your drawable name is background_splash.xml because i think that you wrote wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check carefully your code.
From your image, I am seeing you have: **background_splash.xml**

But your are getting the error:

> I followed the steps line by line, however, I get an error saying the **splash_background.xml** isn't found.

Maybe you typed wrong name somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be `background_splash.xml` instead of `splash_background.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this man:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
}
```